# to get different columns from single query

Tags: mysql, sql

Consider the data about projects and members stored in tables below.  Projects(id, title) Members(id, name, project_id)  Generate a report to list all the projects, members working on them. Also list the projects that do not have any employees assigned yet and also the employees who are available as free resources.

Table-

```
Projects(id, title)     
Members(id, name, project_id)
```

can someone optimize the query as i applied outer join and i got all answers together.i need to  separate the columns as per required question.

```
Select  p.title, m.id
From projects p FULL OUTER JOIN 
     Members m 
where p.id = m.project_id;
```

Comment: Use `ON`, not WHERE.

Comment: @jarlh You could venture an answer here I think.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, probably. Never read the question, just noticed the missing ON.

Comment: What RDBMS is this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL does not support `full join`.  So do this in two steps:

```
Select p.title, m.id
From projects p LEFT JOIN 
     Members m 
     ON p.id = m.project_id
union all
select null, m.id
from members m
where not exists (select 1 from projects p where p.id = m.project_id);
```